# ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED Facebook 4.8.0 SDK Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

My App logs into facebook but when I check the token it returns this error: {accessToken token: ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions: [user_friends, contact_email, email, public_profile]}.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);

    authButton = (LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

    progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    editEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    editSenha = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editSenha);

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

                    MyLog.log("Logged in!...");
                    makeMeRequest(loginResult);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    MyLog.log("Logged out...");
                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    MyLog.log("Logged out...");
                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

    return view;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: could you fix it?

Comment: @Boe-Dev unfortunately no. My boss passed to another company do.